# CSS image change on a timer using keyframes

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have pretty much created a image slide show mainly using css,

I wonder whether it is possible to add a timer on the following [slide show](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/wg8N6/) so that images change every 10 seconds.

from my understanding, the CSS will look something like the following.

```
#homeSlide{  
    animation-name: homeSlider;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes homeSlide img FadeInOut {
   0% {   opacity:1;    }
  45% {   opacity:1;    }
  55% {   opacity:0;    }
 100% {   opacity:0;    }
}
```

Comment: You should try this yourself, and THEN when you have trouble post code that you have tried, or what YOU  have tried and people will be happy to help vs just plain do it for you.

Comment: @Mark I have tried it along with keyframe and it didn't work hence me posting a question it is demonstrated in my jsFiddle example

Comment: Perhaps this will do the trick? http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/#4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I initially just looked at your `jQuery` tag but now that I see adam's link and your tag about `keyframes`. I would be interested to see how this could be done using purely `css`.

Here is an example using JQuery, based on your fiddle.

**Update2**
  Changed `counter=1` instead of `counter=0` to fix the transition so that it does not stay at slide1 for 18 seconds.

```
var imgLength = $("#homeSlide img").length;
var counter = 1;
var imgInterval;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#homeSlide_controls").on('click', 'span', function() {
        $("#homeSlide img").removeClass("opaque");
        var newImage = $(this).index();
        $("#homeSlide img").eq(newImage).addClass("opaque");
        $("#homeSlide_controls span").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        counter = $(this).index();
        clearInterval(imgInterval);
        startInterval();
     });
     startInterval();        
});

function startInterval(){
    imgInterval = setInterval(function(){
            $("#homeSlide img").removeClass("opaque");
            var newImage = counter;
            $("#homeSlide img").eq(newImage).addClass("opaque");
            $("#homeSlide_controls span").removeClass("selected");
            $("#homeSlide_controls span").eq(newImage).addClass("selected");
            counter++;
            if(counter == imgLength){
                counter = 0;
            }
        },9000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wg8N6/3/

Comment: one thing i have noticed is that i get the following message in my browser Uncaught ReferenceError: counter is not defined

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock I am not seeing this error in the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/wg8N6/4/ .. If you are getting this error in your code then you need to make sure you are defining `counter` as a global variable you need to make sure that it is initialized outside of your `$(document).ready(` function and any other function as shown in the fiddle.

Comment: it's not showing up in jsfiddle so i have uploaded it onto my domain, so you can see the error http://iamnatesmithen.com/webapp/slider.php

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock you are missing your variable initialization.. Ad this to the top of your javascript `var imgLength = $("#homeSlide img").length;var counter = 1;var imgInterval;`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help, much appreciated, It would be interested to see this in CSS on a variety of browsers.

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock no problem, if you really like answers to your questions you can upvote them too you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can have some function that reads all these values and performs some javascript, i.e. change to the next image 
then call this function like this:

```
setInterval(YourFunction,3000);
```

SetInterval will execute YourFunction every (in this case) 3000ms
see [the W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) entry for more information on setInterval.

Comment: i take it i will need to take the JS approach and not the CSS approach?

Comment: Well, i might be possible to get it working with css3 animations, but it wouldn't work some some browsers (e.g. < ie10)